# How to get a path for a module imported by importlib, where a class was defined

Tags: python-3.x, python-importlib

There is a nice way to get a path for a module where a class was defined, just do

```
inspect.getfile(obj.__class__)
```

Unfortunately, it seems to break down for files loaded by importlib:

```
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('loaded_module', module_path)
M = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(M)

obj = M.MyClass()
inspect.getfile(obj.__class__)
```

results in

```
  File "/nix/store/z65l1jqvxa58zzwwa3bvglb6asj4y8cv-python3-3.8.5/lib/python3.8/inspect.py", line 665, in getfile
    raise TypeError('{!r} is a built-in class'.format(object))
TypeError: <class 'loaded_module.MyClass'> is a built-in class
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expectation of `inspect.getfile` is that the `class` object (which has a string `__module__` attribute which is the module name) has its module in `sys.modules` (where a module can be looked up by name)

without the module in `sys.modules` it cannot use that chain to find your file

to put it into `sys.modules` you'd do something like:

```py
sys.modules[M.__name__] = M
```

but if you have access to the `M` object somewhere, you can access `.__file__` directly, or if you have access to the `loader`

alternatively, if you know some method is defined on the class in that file, you can interrogate the code object of that function:

```
>>> M.C.__init__.__code__.co_filename
t.py
```

Comment: I wonder, maybe I'm initializing the module somehow incorrectly, so it doesn't get listed in sys.modules?

Comment: nope, putting something into `sys.modules` is entirely separate from the low-level importlib machinery.  there are potential issues with putting things in there (as it's global, name collisions matter, there's semantics about sub-modules, etc.)

Comment: Ideally, I want to call `inspect.getfile(self.__class__)` inside a constructor of a base class and get a file where a child class is defined. But of course I have access to a loader so I can arrange the things to help `getfile` on a later stage

Comment: that seems like a very very strange design -- usually parent classes shouldn't know about their subclasses and usually `inspect` should only be used for debugging

Comment: Hmm. I just want to de-duplicate the code. Basically, each module describes a kind of experiment and it should generate logs in a separate directory. Naming scheme is fixed and tied to a module filename. It's very convenient because it allows me to just copy module files, rename them, tweak a few things and have the module ready for a run.  So it seems very logical to move this logic into a base class.